# Merge common values of certain columns in an excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, merge, xlsxwriter

Consider the DataFrame `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Tesla','Tesla','Tesla','Toyota','Ford','Ford','Ford','BMW','BMW','BMW','Mercedes','Mercedes','Mercedes'],
                   'Type': ['Model X','Model X','Model X','Corolla','Bronco','Bronco','Mustang','3 Series','3 Series','7 Series','C-Class','C-Class','S-Class'],
                   'Year': [2015, 2015, 2015, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2020, 2015, 2015, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2020],
                   'Price': [85000, 90000, 95000, 20000, 35000, 35000, 45000, 40000, 40000, 65000, 50000, 50000, 75000],
                   'Color': ['White','White','White','Red','Blue','Blue','Yellow','Silver','Silver','Black','White','White','Black']
                  })
```

I am trying to merge cells in excel which has common values consecutively for a `DataFrame df` columns using the below `mergecells` function, however, when I open the excel file after merging it says the excel file has recovered some of the values.

```
def mergecells(df, columntomerge, sheetname, writer):
    df1 = df.index.to_series().groupby(df[columntomerge]).agg(['first', 'last']).reset_index()
    df1 = df1.sort_values("first").reset_index()
    first_last_rows = df1.set_index('first')['last'].to_dict()
    merge_ranges = {}
    for key, value in first_last_rows.items():
        if df.loc[key, columnname] in ["Alpha", "-"] or key == value:
            continue
        merge_ranges[df.loc[key, columnname]] = (
            key+1, df.columns.get_loc(columnname), value+1, df.columns.get_loc(columnname))
    wb = writer.book
    ws = writer.sheets[sheetname]
    mf = wb.add_format({'align': 'center', 'valign': 'vcenter'})
    for name, merge_range in merge_ranges.items():
        ws.merge_range(*merge_range, name, mf)
```

```
for col in df.columns:
    mergecells(df,col,'Trial',writer)
```

But when I call the above merge function with the code above, I am getting the error as the below image

[image]

The `Type` column, `Name` column and `Price` column are correctly merged, However the Year and color are completely wrong

Expected Output
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the groupby. You have disjoint intervals while grouping by colors or year: White is found in rows `[1, 2, 3]` but also `[11, 12]`. You should consider consecutive values in a column. `more_itertools.consecutive_groups` can help you with that:

```
from more_itertools import consecutive_groups

sheetname='Sheet1'

with pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheetname, index=False)
    wb = writer.book
    ws = writer.sheets[sheetname]
    mf = wb.add_format({'align': 'center', 'valign': 'vcenter'})

    for j, col in enumerate(df.columns):
        ws.set_column(j, j, 12, mf)
        for val in df[col].unique():
            idx = df[(df[col]==val) & (df[col]==df[col].shift(1))].index   # indices of the rows where the value is the same as the previous row
            for seg in consecutive_groups(idx):
                l = list(seg)
                ws.merge_range(l[0], j, l[-1]+1, j, val, mf)
```